# VSCode - sudo usage switches keyboard language

Tags: mount, keyboard-layout, visual-studio-code

I'm on **MacOS - Mojave with Code version 1.30.2**

I'm experiencing som weird error in Visual Studio Code. I need to run it as super user / sudo because i have a ssh mounted directory and git running - so changing permission and all off that is not possible for the project. And i don't want to type my admin password every time i save a file.

So im currently starting VScode with a script:

`sudo "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron" &>/dev/null &`

Which works fine, but when it open Code the keyboard layout is US (assumed), while om on a nordic keyboard. It works fint when opening code the normal way, eg. typing `code` in terminal.

How can this be, can I set a keyboard layout anywhere? I've searched but didn't find anything...

Edit: The keyboard layout is the correct on the Mac, and works in all other programs.

Thanks!